# How do I changed the saved zoom level of a map saved in Google Maps "My Places"

Tags: google-maps

I saved two places to one of my maps in Google Maps My Places.

I want to embed this map on a webpage.

The zoom is too close.  I want to zoom out 2 units.  How do save the new zoom level to my map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never realised where the embed button was.

It is the chain link icon at the top right of the left hand column.

Clicking this brings up the embed options, which includes the ability to set the zoom.